# Is it bad practice to use a function expression as an argument to another function?

Tags: c

I defined a function that converts GSL vectors to arrays.
The function returns a pointer to an array.

```
double * vec2array(const gsl_vector * v){
  double * out = calloc(v->size,sizeof(double));
  for( int i = 0; i < v->size; i++ ){
    out[i] = gsl_vector_get(v,i);
  }
  return out;
}
```

is it bad practice to do use the return value as an argument to another function 
i.e:

```
plot(vec2array(x),vec2array(y));
```

is that a memory leak?

Comment: If you have such basic questions, having a C book ready might be a good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using return values of functions directly as arguments, per se.

Your particular use of it does leak memory, however. This is simple to see, since you never call `free()` on the memory you got from `calloc()`. (Unless your `plot()` function calls `free()`, at least.)